# How can I add animation to an automotive style dojo gauge?

Tags: dojo, xpages, easing

I have a simple dojo gauge, and I would like to add animation so the needle moves from 0 to it's value when the page loads.  I like the easing option for elasticOut, but I don't know how to use it.  Can someone help me to implement it?

[image: Gauge]

This code snippet is from my xpages custom control that uses custom properties for each of the indicator values.

```
if (_indType == "Needle") {
    gauge.addIndicator(new dojox.widget.gauge.AnalogNeedleIndicator({
        'value': parseInt(_indValue),'color': _indColor,'width': parseInt(_indWidth),noChange: true,useRangeStyles: 8
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If available out-of-the-box, the `animationDuration` property looks the most likely, see http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/dgauges.html. If not, you may need to extend the relevant Dojo widget class.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Paul.  I did see that page, but was unable to get anything to work.  I found this post http://jsfiddle.net/rastrano/ZSrF8/   that shows a moving needle, but when I tried to apply it, it didn't work either.  I'm hoping to find a working example that I can use.